SSRS Timeslice Pivot Report Formatting
I have an SSRS Report that includes a Time slice Pivot table by hour as a column group. The group has 2 columns in it with 2 different Sums for each hour.  I am trying to format the report to alternate colors for each hour.  Is there an expression or a way to do that.  I can only find a way to alternate colors for each column, not the grouping.
I tried to change the fill colors but it only changed each column, not each column group.
